# VB.NET Select String Matching Pattern

Tags: regex, vb.net

I know how to test for a pattern using the 'like' operator in VB.NET but what I wish to do is test for the pattern that can appear at any point in the string and return it.

I.e

```
Dim _MyString As String = "Dave 01-LYJX01PC01 XXYZABC"
Dim _MyString2 As String = "Dave XXYZABC 01-LYJX01PC01"

If _MyString LIKE "##-????##??##" Then
 Console.WriteLine(_MyString )
End If
```

Now I know the above but what I wish to do is return the text that matches the pattern.

I could be missing something really basic here, but I've looked that long im struggling and need another opinion.

Cheers

Comment: The `Like` operator is just for comparison purposes, if you need to return the string that matched then you will need to use an actual RegEx engine (which I believe you now have an answer for below) in order to return a match collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\d{2}-\p{L}{4}\d{2}\p{L}{2}\d{2}
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cp%7BL%7D%7B4%7D%5Cd%7B2%7D%5Cp%7BL%7D%7B2%7D%5Cd%7B2%7D&i=Dave%2001-LYJX01PC01%20XXYZABC%0D%0ADave%20XXYZABC%2001-LYJX01PC01)

If it is a substring that is always a whole word, enclose this pattern with word boundaries: `\b\d{2}-\p{L}{4}\d{2}\p{L}{2}\d{2}\b`.

VB.NET snippet:

```
Dim my_rx As Regex = New Regex("\d{2}-\p{L}{4}\d{2}\p{L}{2}\d{2}")
Dim my_matches As List(Of String) = my_rx.Matches("Dave 01-LYJX01PC01 XXYZABC").Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToList()
Dim my_matches2 As List(Of String) = my_rx.Matches("Dave XXYZABC 01-LYJX01PC01").Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToList()
```

**UPDATE**

Since you will always have 1 match in the input string, you can use simple code:

```
Dim my_result As Match = my_rx.Match("Dave XXYZABC 01-LYJX01PC01")
If my_result.Success Then
   Console.WriteLine(my_result)
End If
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/vq701H)

Comment: I used `\p{L}` to represent `?` just because your strings contain letters in those places. If there can be any character but whitespace, you can use `\S`. If there can be any character, use `.` (with `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag, it will even match newlines).

Comment: I have a string that is "REF: 02-IJZ07PC01 -C<RPost Receipt>RTA Delivery Receipt" but the Regex does not recognize it as a match? How come? The same ##-????##??## appears?

Comment: It is not the same, as there are only 3 letters `IJZ` after `-`. What are your actual requirements? Anyway, to match both previous and this format, you can use [`\d{2}-\p{L}{3,4}\d{2}\p{L}{2}\d{2}`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cp%7bL%7d%7b3%2c4%7d%5cd%7b2%7d%5cp%7bL%7d%7b2%7d%5cd%7b2%7d&i=REF%3a+02-IJZ07PC01+-C%3cRPost+Receipt%3eRTA+Delivery+Receipt%0d%0aDave+XXYZABC+01-LYJX01PC01).

Comment: Ah HA! That's an error in the subject line then, my apologies.

Comment: If I know the resulting match is always going to be 1 record because I am only dealing with 1 record at a time, how would I go about putting it direct into 1 variable. I changed the ToList() to a ToString() but it didn't return the result of the regex.

Comment: You need to just use `.Match(str).Value`. I will update the answer right away.

Answer (score -1):

What you need is write string 'Matches' in console?

If right you must encap 'Matches' with double quote.

```
Console.WriteLine("Matches")
```

Comment: If you need to clarify the OP question, please add a comment. This is not what the OP is requesting.

Comment: That's okay, we all learn somewhere - just keep in mind for future reference :)